# Passing AuthenticationManager to Custom Filter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

Since the Spring Security got updated, I had to do some changes in my code. This is my configuration class now.

```
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;


    public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService, UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .addFilter(new CustomAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new CustomAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), userRepository))
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user/users/save").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users//register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll() // Only for testing purposes
                .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/user/**").authenticated();
        return http.build();
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

However, since I have changed the configure method and the authentication manager to beans, I am not able to pass the authentication manager to my filters. Which look like this.

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Value("${security.key}")
    private String secretKey;

    public CustomAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        LoginRequest loginRequest = null;
        try {
            loginRequest = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), LoginRequest.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        String username = loginRequest.getUsername();
        String password = loginRequest.getPassword();
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
        return authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        UserDetailsImpl user = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
        Algorithm algorithm = HMAC512(secretKey.getBytes());
        List<String> list = user.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toList());
        String accessToken = JWT.create()
                .withSubject(user.getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+10*60*1000))
                .withClaim("authorities", list)
                .sign(algorithm);
        response.addHeader("authorization","Bearer " + accessToken);
    }

}
```

How can I inject the authenticationManager to my filter?

Answer (score 8):

The recommended way to access the `AuthenticationManager` is by using a [custom DSL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html#jc-custom-dsls). This is actually how Spring Security internally implements methods like `HttpSecurity.authorizeRequests()`.

```java
public class MyCustomDsl extends AbstractHttpConfigurer<MyCustomDsl, HttpSecurity> {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class);
        http.addFilter(new CustomAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager));
    }

    public static MyCustomDsl customDsl() {
        return new MyCustomDsl();
    }
}
```

The custom DSL can then be applied when building the `SecurityFilterChain`:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // ...
    http.apply(customDsl());
    return http.build();
}
```

This is described in the [blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter#disqus_thread) on migrating away from the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, under the section "Accessing the local AuthenticationManager".

Comment: Is this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73886487/what-is-the-alternative-to-the-authenticationmanagerbean-function-after-the-webs answered by your answer? If yes, I would vote to close the other question. If not, could you answer the other question? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I face same problem, solved:

```
public class SecurityConfig {

   @Autowired
   private AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration;

   @Bean
   protected SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.addFilterBefore(new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager()), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
   }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

I guess this should work (since all the calls to @Bean methods are proxied via CGLIB and therefore the cached version of the bean is returned):

```
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration;


    public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService, UserRepository userRepository, AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.authenticationConfiguration = authenticationConfiguration;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .addFilter(new CustomAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new CustomAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), userRepository))
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user/users/save").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users//register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll() // Only for testing purposes
                .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/user/**").authenticated();
        return http.build();
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

If there is circular dependencies issue, you can place @Lazy annotation on AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration in constructor.