# What is the alternative to the authenticationManagerBean function after the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class has been deprecated?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

In Spring Boot 2.7.4, the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`class which contains the `authenticationManagerBean` function is deprecated

What is the alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that the alternative is the `getAuthenticationManager` function in the `AuthenticationConfiguration` class

```java
    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain configure(final HttpSecurity http,
                                            final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth,
                                            final AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        // set the authentication provider
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());

        // set the authorization and authentication rules
        return http
                .csrf().disable()
                // Make sure that the session is stateless because we are using JWT
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                // Add the JWT filter (my custom filter)
                .addFilter(new JwtFilter(authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager()))
                .build();
}
```

Comment: these changes should be happen with newer changes

.csrf().disable()   =>  csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())

.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)  => .sessionManagement(auth -> auth.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))

Answer (score 5):

I have been facing the same problem as you these days, the only solution found is this

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}
```

But this is causing me an exception in testing.
I posted a spring-boot issue on GitHub.  Take a look to keep up to date.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29215
It could be a bug