# Authentication Manager in CustomFilter, with Filter Chain

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, jwt

I am facing the issue with injecting Authentication Manager in my CustomFilter.

My Web Security Config Code

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebSecurityConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                //TODO secure endpoints
//                .antMatchers("/client/**").hasAuthority("CLIENT")
//                .antMatchers("/producer/**").hasAuthority("PRODUCER")
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.cors();
        http.addFilter(new CustomAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(ERROR))); 

        return http.build();
    }


    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
    }

}
```

my CustomFilter code

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = request.getParameter("email");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        log.info("username is: {}, password is: {}", username, password);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
        return authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        User user = (User)authResult.getPrincipal();
        Algorithm secret = Algorithm.HMAC256("myAwesomeSecret".getBytes());
        String access_token = JWT.create()
                .withSubject(user.getEmail())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 60 * 60 * 1000))
                .withIssuer(request.getRequestURL().toString())
                .withClaim("userRole", user.getUserRole().toString())
                .sign(secret);
        response.setHeader("access_token", access_token);
    }
}
```

The issue occurs in this line

```
        http.addFilter(new CustomAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(ERROR)));
```

I don't know how to work with authenticationConfiguration to create my authenticationManager.

In WebMvcConfigurerAdapter we could get authenticaion manager simply by calling overriden method authenticationManagerBean().

How can i inject Authenticaion Manager to my Custom Filter ?

I tried to inject authentication manager in my Web Security Config, hoping that spring will create that bean for me, and then inject it into filterChain, but i was facing issue with circulal beans or something like that.

SOLVED :

```
        http.addFilter(new CustomAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationConfiguration.class))));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing AuthenticationManager to Custom Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72509142/passing-authenticationmanager-to-custom-filter)

Answer (score 0):

You could just inject the `AuthenticationManager` into you `filterChain` method, something like this:

```java
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, AuthenticationManager authManager) throws Exception {
        // ...
        http.addFilter(new CustomAuthenticationFilter(authManager)); 

        return http.build();
    }


    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
```